# Why does TFS Power Tools 2013 installation not ask me if I want to install the PowerShell Cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, tfs

We have a PowerShell script that utilises the TFS PowerShell snapin (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell).

When installing the TFS 2013 Power Tools on my development workstation, the "PowerShell Cmdlets" feature is missing from the list of available features in the Custom Setup.

Please see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWe4r.png

A colleague of mine has the PowerShell Cmdlets in his Custom Setup feature list.

Please see - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiWDT.png

I didn't have this problem with the TFS 2012 Power Tools. Why is the "PowerShell Cmdlets" feature hidden in my Custom Setup list?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install power shell 3.0 first.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thanks for responding. I am currently running PowerShell version 4. If I try and install PowerShell 3.0 as part of Windows Management Framework 3.0 then I am told - "The update is not applicable to your computer."

Comment: I just tried to install TFS 2013 Power Tools again and I now have the option to install the PowerShell Cmdlets. What's changed? I recently updated to VS2013 Update 2. Previously, I just had a bog standard VS2013 install, not even Update 1. Maybe that was it?