# Installing TFS PowerShell Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, tfs

Similar to these two questions

[How to use TFS Powershell commands from 2013 Power Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513338/how-to-use-tfs-powershell-commands-from-2013-power-tools)

[Why does TFS Power Tools 2013 installation not ask me if I want to install the PowerShell Cmdlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563816/why-does-tfs-power-tools-2013-installation-not-ask-me-if-i-want-to-install-the-p)

I cannot get the TFS PowerShell Cmdlets installed.  During the install, I am not prompted to install them.  And, in fact, the Typical Install text states it will not install them.  After installing, then going in to modify, I do not see PowerShell Cmdlets in the list of features.

I am on TFS 2013 Update 4 and PowerShell 4.0.  How do I install these Cmdlets on the TFS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, either Visual Studio or Team Explorer (which uses the VS Shell) are pre-requisites for the Cmdlets (among other things).  Because of company policy, neither application was installed on the server.  After installing Team Explorer (deemed the lesser of two "evils") I was able to install and use the TFS Cmdlets.